# How to make a sprite jump in cocos2d 3.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a game in Cocos2d 3.0 and I can't find much in the way of tutorials. I was hoping for someone to teach me how to make a sprite jump when you press swipe up on the left side of the screen (iphone is in landscape).

Not sure if this is needed but my sprite implementation code is below.

```
daveRunSG = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"char1.png"];
daveRunSG.position = ccp(100, 130);
CCActionAnimate *animAction = [CCActionAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCActionRepeatForever *animationRepeatFor = [CCActionRepeatForever actionWithAction:animAction];
[daveRunSG.texture setAntialiased:NO];
[daveRunSG runAction:animationRepeatFor];
[self addChild:daveRunSG];
```

Thanks in advance for any help I receive.

Comment: Im sorry, but the amazing people at StackOverflow are not here to teach you. Please try to get as far as you can yourself and come back when you run into a spefic problem. Nobody here will do your job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an impulse to the character's physics body. It must be a child of a physics node and have the physics set up.

```
[daveRunSG.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(0, 1600)];
```

Also, if you're looking for some good tutorials you should visit https://www.makegameswith.us or http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/cocos2d